# Приложение как служба Android

Tags: java, android

Приложение gps трекер. `Activity`, которое отображает состояние трекера(подключение к инету, к серверу и т.п.) и `Service`, который и выполняет всю работу.

Хочется реализовать такую вещь: приложение запускается один раз, запускается `Service` и работает сам по себе, даже если активити было убито системой, или после перезапуска устройства сервис сам "поднимался" и выполнял работу в виде службы.

**Вопрос:** возможно ли такое реализовать? Если да, то как? Что можно почитать по этому поводу?
Т.е. идея такая, чтобы сделать `Service` независимым от `Activity` и работал сам по себе (как-то так, не знаю, как это точно и грамотно сформулировать).

Comment: возможно. Почитать можно гугл. например, по запросу `android start on boot` (это про `после перезапуска устройства сервис сам "поднимался"`), по поводу `даже если активити было убито системой` - `android service stops when activity is closed`

Comment: @metalurgus, как к этому относятся в гугле при публикации в маркет?

Comment: Это обычная практика, абсолютно нормальная.

Comment: На сколько я помню Service как раз работает до тех пор, пока его явно не остановят, связанное приложение может быть неактивно.

Comment: @Viktor, нет. Обычный сервис умрет вместе с `Activtiy`, либо вместе с процессом приложения.

Comment: @metalurgus, тогда может, как вариант, запускать сервис в отдельном процессе?

Comment: в гугле по запроссам, которые я написал есть ответы, которые, кстати, @VAndrJ уже нагуглил вместо вас (см. его ответ)

Comment: @metalurgus, 
Сервис в foreground-e, есть иконка в панели уведомлений, активити в фоне висит. Если убрать активити из фона, сервис по прежнему должен работать и иконка должна быть в панели уведомлений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте  [Foreground service](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/services.html)

Для запуска при рестарте телефона создайте `BroadcastReceiver` на `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"`

Comment: если использовать `foreground service`, то сервис будет запускаться без активити?

Comment: @Dev_Vlad, будет, проверено на практике в одном из приложений, при получении `broadcast` запускается сервис, висит до получения `broadcast`а, по которому нужно его убить.

Comment: ок, спасибо, буду тестировать это дело)

Comment: Сервис в `foreground`-e, есть иконка в панели уведомлений, активити в фоне висит. Если убрать активити из фона, сервис по прежнему должен работать и иконка должна быть в панели уведомлений?